# how to call web service by supplying credentials in Palm WebOS

Tags: webos, palm-pre, palm

I am able to call a web service that doesn't require server credentials. But I need to call a web service which require server credentials(username and password) for authentication. How to call this type of web services by supplying appropriate credentials using Ajax.Request or any other method in Palm WebOS.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Is the user supplying the credentials, or are you hard-coding the credentials into your application?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Basic Authentication you could try this: [Using Authentication with Ajax.Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298891/using-authentication-with-ajax-request)