# Encryption in Palm WebOS

Tags: javascript, ajax, encryption, md5, webos

My question is related to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913300/how-to-call-web-service-by-supplying-credentials-in-palm-webos). I know how to send the credentials to a service. What I need is a way to encrypt those credentials. In browser javascript/ajax, when I need to access a service, I put an ajax call in to a php script, which used hash_hmac('md5', $data, $key) as the encryption method. I need to use md5, but Mojo.model.encrypt in webos only uses Blowfish.

My question is how can I implement md5 encryption in webos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your own MD5 library.  Some of the on-device apps shipped by Palm actually do this.  One BSD-licensed implementation is available at http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/md5.html.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's a service for this now: https://developer.palm.com/content/api/reference/services/key-manager.html